# Firebase with async/await but i cant deploy there is an error that i can use async

Tags: javascript, firebase, babeljs

how can I deploy this work?

1. I found out that firebase javascript doesn't support async/await have to use typescript: I don't know typescript.
2. I need to convert my project using babel: don't work, is this deprecated?

Can I know is there any other method to make async works in firebase?